# Vite build error 'Unexpected early exit' when using web worker

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, web-worker

I'm building a Nuxt3/Vue3 app and using a web worker for my project to process images in the background of the browser. For this scenario, I'm using the @jsquash/avif library to process images to avif format. This works fine on the dev server, I've encountered an issue that arises only when I try to build the project for production.

I'm using the import with Query Suffixes method that [vite provides](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#web-workers), although I did try to import the worker with a constructor also to no avail.

These are my files:

./composables/useUtils.ts

```
import convertWorker from "@/assets/workers/convertWorker?worker";

 const convertToAvifFile = (file, name) => {
    return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
       if (window.Worker) {
         const convWorker = convertWorker();

          convWorker.postMessage(loadedImage);
          convWorker.onmessage = async (e) => {
            const base64String = "data:image/jpg;base64," + arrayBufferToBase64(e.data);
            const avifBlob = await dataUrlToFile(base64String, name, "image/avif");
            res(avifBlob);
          };
      }
 }
```

./assets/workers/convertWorker.js

```
import { encode } from "@jsquash/avif";

onmessage = async (val) => {
  const avifBuffer = await encode(val.data);

   postMessage(avifBuffer);
 };
```

When i run npm build this is the error that gets thrown

```
 Unexpected early exit. This happens when Promises returned by plugins cannot resolve. Unfinished hook action(s) on exit:
   (vite:worker) transform "C:/Users/cab_l/Desktop/Repositories/wsp-3.0/assets/workers/convertWorker.js?worker"
```

I was wondering if this is a vite bug and if anyone has figured any way to fix/workaround it?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: Hello, yes after a lengthy discussion with the creator of the library we managed to hash out a workaround for the bug. You can find it here https://github.com/jamsinclair/jSquash#known-issues